# Find primitive element of splitting field extension of $x^4 - 5$ over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: field-theory, splitting-field

A splitting field extension of $x^4 - 5$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is $K = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{5}, i)$, and $[K:\mathbb{Q}] = 8$.

Let $\alpha = \sqrt[4]{5}$ and $\gamma = \alpha + i$. I'm trying to show $\gamma$ is a primitive element, and it is getting complicated. On a computer, I get

$$\begin{aligned}
{\gamma}^2 &= {\alpha}^2 + 2\alpha i - 1 \\
{\gamma}^3 &= {\alpha}^3 + 3{\alpha}^2i - 3\alpha - i \\
{\gamma}^4 &= 4{\alpha}^3i - 6{\alpha}^2 - 4{\alpha}i + 6 \\
{\gamma}^5 &= -10{\alpha}^3 - 10{\alpha}^2i + 10\alpha + 26i \\
{\gamma}^6 &= -20{\alpha}^3i + 20{\alpha}^2 + 36{\alpha}i - 76 \\
{\gamma}^7 &= 40{\alpha}^3 + 56{\alpha}^2i - 112\alpha - 176i
\end{aligned}$$

Next, I look at the coefficients of $\gamma, {\gamma}^3, {\gamma}^5$, and ${\gamma}^7$ to form a $4 \times 4$ matrix.  On a computer again, I then check that the matrix is invertible, and so there are linear combinations to solve for $\alpha$ and $i$.  Thus $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{5}, i) \subseteq \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{5} + i)$.

Is there an easier solution?

By the way, this problem is in Chapter 7 of the book on Galois theory by Garling, and Galois groups are not yet covered. A more elementary solution is expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it this way, without any linear algebra, because this is a rather simple situation:

Consider $\alpha$ as an irrationality over the Gaussian numbers, $\Bbb Q(i)$. You know that $X^4-5$ is still irreducible as a $\Bbb Z[i]$-polynomial, because $(5)$, though not a prime, is product of two distinct primes, $5=(2+i)(2-i)$, and Eisenstein applies. That is, $f(X)=\text{Irr}\bigl(\alpha,\Bbb Q(i)[X]\bigr)=X^4-5$ and by translation, $\text{Irr}\bigl(\alpha+i,\Bbb Q(i)[X]\bigr)=f(X-i)=X^4-4iX^3-6X^2+4iX-4=g(X)$. Now your desired polynomial is just $g(X)\overline g(X)$, where the bar is complex conjugation of each coefficient.

Comment: Thanks! I see. Then $[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha + i):\mathbb{Q}(i)] = 4$ so $[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha + i):\mathbb{Q}] = 8$, and $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha + i)$ must be all of $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha, i)$.  What is the part about $g(X)\overline{g}(X)$? Is that the minimal polynomial of $\alpha + i$ over $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: Yes, it is the minimal $\Bbb Q$-polynomial of $\alpha+i$. You see that its coeffs are in $\Bbb Q$, yes? And you see that it has the right degree? And you see that $\alpha+i$ is a root? That is enough.

Comment: Great, yes, I see. The complex roots come in conjugate pairs to bring the polynomial to real coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}(i)[x]$, so in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$, and the polynomial has the required degree 8 with $\alpha + i$ a root.